# How to import values from the 2nd sheet based on the colum of the 1st sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have two sheets -

Sheet1 includes:

```
col 1  | col 2 
[Name] | [phones ]
```

Sheet2 includes:

```
col 1  | col 2
[Name] | [e-mail]
```

I want to `importrange` if the name on `Sheet1` is equal to name on `Sheet2`.

Comment: Welcome. The question isn't clear. What means `[Name].[phones ]`,`[Name].[e-mail]` and `[sheet1.name] [sheet2.Email]`?

Comment: is  column '.....

Comment: col1= name col2= phones on sheet1

Comment: Col1= name Col2= phons on sheet2

Comment: I want to import data only  if col1 on sheet1 (=) or like * col 1on sheet 2

Comment: my sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksvkX8E8nkB-inB8azDdJXUJhSeYFBiOYH0l-sK8-us/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use **`VLOOKUP`** formula. paste this formula in cell **C1** on **Sheet2**:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0), ))
  ```

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(Sheet1!A1:A,
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&A1:A&"*",A1:A))), Sheet1!A1:B, 2, 0), ))
  ```

Comment: thanks my dear for your time .... you are the best